# Unit testing a task with just one public method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm finding in this situation: I've a legacy service (written in C#) that just runs three threads that do some different stuff, suppose three different tasks. Now each of this task needs to be unit tested because on production stage we have a lot of bugs, unhandled exceptions and so on that makes our developers' life very difficult.

What's strange in my opinion is that obviously these task just expose one public method (suppose Run) and, if this is correct, I think I should unit test this one. Am I correct? How would you approach this kind of job? Which kind of refactoring would you perform?

Comment: This question is very vague, it doesn't even specify which *language*. Can you provide an example class? I also recommend reading [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://tinyurl.com/WELCBook) to get some hints on how to add unit tests to a legacy codebase.

Comment: Hi Johnsyweb, you are right this is a very vague question but I don't know how to make it clearer. I edited adding the language (C#). I cannot provide an example class (as it's very big) but it's formed by a lot of private methods (with void returns) that are just called in chain starting from a public method. Thanks

Comment: Can't you test all *those* public methods?

Comment: They AREN'T public... That's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with testing a legacy class with only one public method that runs a lot of code internal is that it will never come down to the level of a Unit Test.

The nicest solution would be to refactor your code to such a level you can inject all dependencies so you can test all code paths.

If that's not possible you to control the environment the tests run in. By differing the setup for your  tests in such a way that each of the three tasks is separately run, you could check each result independently and force all error paths.

Comment: Hi Wouter de Kort! This is what I'm trying to do: refactor and inject dependendency and test paths. Do you think that's the best solution?

Comment: @Marconline Yes that is definitely the way to go. You want to Unit Test the logic in your current class, not in the logic that your class depends on (they should have separate unit tests). Dependency injection helps with this. Check for more info on testable code: http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/

Comment: I mostly removed the concrete classes from the code replacing with interfaces. I test a derived class that inherits from my class. This class overrides some methods and injects stubs and mocks to the main class. If you tell me this is the correct way to behave, than I'll go through this path. Thanks, Marco

Comment: Do you really need to override methods? This could change the behavior of your SUT. Can't you test the real class and inject dependencies?

Comment: These are the case I override methods:
1. ReturnItems() - this method gets data invoking method from a dependency. Instead of use the dependency, I override the method and inject what's the return of this method.
2. Verify that a particular method is called

Do you think these are not good?

Marco

Comment: If you use dependency injection in combination with Mocking you can setup these expectations in a more natural way that won't require subclassing. What if you want to return a different result for another test? Then you would have to create another subclass. That's a path you don't want to take. Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/moq/ for some info on what Mocking is.

Answer (score 0):

OK. First have a clear view on what the task you want to test is doing. Then think about separation of concerns: are there parts of that code that you can extract to separate classes, and inject through interface dependency injection? You can use adapter or listener patterns for example, or just plain external collaborators injected into your main class. If so, do it. Then, test independently each one.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, yes. I'm trying to do this. Separe the concerns and then test each class indipendently. That's the correct way in your opinion?